# Pass a classname variable string to a generic method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a static method which has a return type to get the type of dictionary object as shown below

```
public static Type returnTypeDict<T>()
    {

        Dictionary<string, List<T>> d = new Dictionary<string, List<T>>();
        var constructed = d.GetType();
        return constructed;
    }
```

I  am trying to use the above method like this but not working in this fashion

```
string className = "CustomerAddress";
string namespaceName = "Customer.API.Models";
var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(namespaceName + "." + className));
 var constructed = returnTypeDict<myObj>();
```

I need the className to be a variable so that I can change it based on few conditions..How can I achieve this.

Comment: [Type.MakeGenericType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: Thank you for the tip but still stuck at how to pass the class object from a variable of string type.  string className = "CustomerAddress". I will be getting the class names only in string format which map exactly to my classNames

Comment: *Thank you for the tip but still stuck at how to pass the class object from a variable of string type.* -- but you are already doing `Type.GetType(namespaceName + "." + className)`, is that not working?

Comment: No dbc.. at this line  var constructed = returnTypeDict<myObj>();  getting an error myObj is a variable but used as type.